# ag-floating-bottom and ag-body keeps increasing top value

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using Angular5 with typescript. The issue is that the table is empty (has no data), but the height of the table keeps increasing and does not stop increasing.

This is what I have in my HTML:

```
<ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions"></ag-grid-angular>
```

When I view it in the page, the Loading icon keeps moving down and the top values keep changing: [image]

Comment: what's your issue? visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you figure out whats causing it?

Comment: I had to add the ag-grid .style files to polyfill to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same issue and in my case the issue was to do with mismatch in the following versions of the following packages

ag-grid-angular
ag-grid-community

The issue was occuring only when I was using one of the pre-defined ag themes in the ag-grid-community - 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css'

When I do not set any theme ( default browser setting ) I did not notice this issue

It might be worth checking if the versions of these two packages are the same before trying out other solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by "the mismatch"?

Comment: When I noticed this error the versions of these 2 packages were not the same. ag-grid-angular : 18.2.X, ag-grid-community: 20.2.0

Comment: How did you check that? What did you do to solve the problem? And what is the problem in having two different versions? Please add all such explanation to the answer itself (not to the comment section) such that others can learn from it

Comment: Honestly I dont know why this solved the issue in my case. My knowledge of angular/ag-grid is very very basic and I am not a Web UI developer.
However it might be worth adding that I noticed this ever expanding grid issue when I was using one of the pre-defined themes from ag-grid-community - ag-theme-balham 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css'. If I used the browser default this was not occuring